# VBA get workbook object to the workbook that opend it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code in excel (let's call the workbook "WB1") that opens a workbook in a new excel application instance (call it WB2).
I would like WB2 to be able to reference WB1 and insert values to cells in it. My goal is to have WB2 run some tasks i parallel to WB1 and insert the results to WB1, without slowing the usage of WB1 (which is the user interface).

I don't want it to use the workbook name, since there might be several excel instances open with the same workbook name.

I tried to use WB1 to run a macro on WB2 using application.run and inserting the WB1 object as a parameter for WB2 to save as a global variable, but when i try to call it after the macro is finished, it stays empty.
This is the code i tried using:

```
Call app.Run(WB2.Name & "!Module1.GetWB1Object", ThisWorkbook)
```

I thought about these possible solutions, but i don't know if they are possible:

1. Inserting the PID number of WB1 using a module in WB1 to a cell in WB2 and using this PID to create a workbook object.
2. Inserting some sort of object reference of WB1 to a cell in WB2 using a module from WB1 or by calling a module in WB2, and then creating a workbook object.

This is the code i use to open the excel file (in WB1):

```
Dim app As New Excel.Application
Dim WB2 As Excel.Workbook

app.Visible = True
Set WB2 = app.Workbooks.Add("WB2.xlsm")
```

Dose someone have an idea how it is possible?

Comment: 1st thing, you cannot open 2 workbook with the same name at the same time

Comment: Why are you using `Workbooks.Add`? That's going to create a new workbook using `WB2.xlsm` as a template.

Comment: @KinSiang. Your statement is partially correct. It should be "You cannot open 2 workbook with the same name at the same time in the same Excel Instance" ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Is it possible to open 2 excel with same name? Even it is possible, i think it is a bad practise to have same excel name for different data..

Comment: @noire Yes, having it opened as a template fits my goal

Comment: @KinSiang: Yes it is possible to open 2 workbook with the same name at the same time in different Excel Instances.

Comment: Excel's model is to open/create file as workbook into memory, make changes in memory, then write out result.  How, within that paradigm, do you expect to share results?  The two instances of Excel will not share any memory and will not communicate with each other.

Comment: @Chris Maurer  But I can use the WB2 object to access data on WB2 from WB1 even though they are at different instances. I can fetch data from cells, insert data to cells and call function on WB2. I just don't know how to do the opposite

Comment: Does someone have any ideas?